# Duplicate PATH entries - don't know where they're being set from

Tags: bash, fedora, terminal, path

TL;DR something changing my path, triplicating my custom directories even when commenting out the `export PATH=` line from bashrc

---

Recently I added a line to my `.bashrc` to add two custom directories to the path:

```
export PATH=~/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:~/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

All looks fine, no problems. Today, however, I checked my path to see which directories I had and discovered the custom directories were there three times:

```
echo $PATH
/home/myusername/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:/home/myusername/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/myusername/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:/home/myusername/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/myusername/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:/home/myusername/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/home/myusername/bin
```

Strange, I thought to myself. I'll comment out the line from my bashrc - it must be being sourced three times for some reason. Open a new tab in the terminal - the first pair of custom directories is gone but the other two are **still there**:

```
/home/myusername/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:/home/myusername/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/myusername/Documents/Code/Own/Scripts/:/home/myusername/Misc/Applications/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/home/myusername/bin
```

So, maybe this is just a problem with GNOME Terminal saving the path with each session. Logged in through a TTY and the path was correct - no dupe entries (my bashrc was still sourced via a line bash_profile). However, using xterm the problem was still present - meaning it's not down to something with GNOME terminal.

What I don't understand is what file is changing the path when I've commented out the line from the bashrc and never added it anywhere else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open a new tab in GNOME terminal, it copies the environment to the new shell rather than creating a new empty environment. Personally I think that's a mistake (and it's one of the reasons why I won't use GNOME terminal myself) but I'm sure the developers have their reasons. After starting a new tab and copying the environment, it then starts your shell, which goes through its normal interactive startup routine, which involves sourcing `.bashrc`

If you want to avoid your addition being done several times, you have a few options:

- switch to a different terminal emulator
- don't do the modification in `.bashrc`, but instead in `.bash_profile`, which is part of the login procedure rather than the interactive startup and therefore shouldn't be used on a new tab (but obviously it's possible that GNOME terminal is even more broken than I thought and it might still start the shell in a way that sources `.bash_profile`, after all; it's been quite a while since I last used it)
- check whether the PATH variable already contains the needed modification before making it again.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by logging out and in again, so it must've been caused by something I did earlier in my session.